# rsyslog- what's the difference between $ModLoad and module(load)?

Tags: rsyslog

I'm on an RHEL 7.7 machine:

Linux myhost 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 18 20:25:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Running rsyslog-8.24.0-38.el7.x86_64

According to the rsyslog docs (currently in 2021 located at  https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/converting_to_new_format.html), `$ModLoad` is obsolete and replaced by `module(load=`. So I've tried it and I've noticed they're not equivalent. My question is, why is the new format not acting like the old?

For reference, here's the entry from the documentation:

> Converting Module Load
>
> This is very straight-forward. In obsolete legacy format we use:
>
> `$ModLoad module-name`
>
> This is very simply converted to:
>
> `module(load="module-name")`

When I do this in my `rsyslog.conf` file:

```
$ModLoad imuxsock.so    # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imklog.so      # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
```

restart rsyslog, then do: `systemctl restart crond`, I notice this in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Mar  8 18:16:19 myhost systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Mar  8 18:16:24 myhost systemd[1]: Stopping Command Scheduler...
Mar  8 18:16:24 myhost systemd[1]: Stopped Command Scheduler.
Mar  8 18:16:24 myhost systemd[1]: Started Command Scheduler.
```

But when convert to the modern configuration, like this:

```
module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
module(load="imklog") # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
```

(changing only those two lines) I see this:

```
Mar  8 18:18:40 myhost rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0-38.el7" x-pid="28876" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

No mention of the crond restart.

I've also tried, just for grins:

```
module(load="imuxsock.so") # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
module(load="imklog.so") # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
```

No difference in behavior.

Edit:
I notice that if a file /etc/rsyslog.d/listen.conf exists, and it contains

```
$SystemLogSocketName /run/systemd/journal/syslog
```

then I get the behavior described, along with an error message in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Mar  8 18:45:13 myhost rsyslogd: command 'SystemLogSocketName' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.24.0-38.el7 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
```

but only if I use the new style of module loading. Which means that it's not "very simply converted", at least in my mind.

If I remove that listen.conf file, then I get no logging of a crond restart in `/var/log/messages` at all.

Now I wonder how I *can* get the `/var/log/messages` logging with the new style module load syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the whole, rsyslog does a good job allowing legacy options from 20 years ago to co-exist with all the enormous changes made since.

Note that a `$ModLoad` line can have many other lines providing options for that module. For example, the `$SystemLogSocketName` option you found corresponds to the imuxsock `module()` option `SysSock.Name=`.

You should look at all the other non-commented-out lines beginning `$` and convert them to appropriate module parameters.

Comment: This worked:
`module(load="imuxsock"   SysSock.name="/run/systemd/journal/syslog")`
and I had to get rid of the old garbage about `$SystemLogSocketName`. Thanks!!!